# Syntax Error In Python Function

Tags: python, syntax

I have checked everything that I could to try and fix this code. It may just be something stupid that I didn't see but I literally learned this language today. I keep getting invalid syntax. Can someone look over my code?

```
import glob, os, datetime, sys, time, shutil


def rename(dir1, dir2):
    filenum = 1
    date = time.strftime("%d%m%Y")
    fileiter = glob.iglob(os.path.join(dir1, r'*.mp4')
    for filen in fileiter:
        print(filen);
        filename = dir2 + filen + date + filenum + r'.mp4'
        filedir1 = dir1 + filen
        shutil.copy2(filedir1, dir2);
        filedir2 = dir2 + filen
        os.rename(filedir2, filename);
    print("Copying Done!");        
return;

starting_dir = input("Enter Input Directory: ")
if len(starting_dir) == 0:
    print("Actually Enter Enter Something")
    sys.exit()
output_dir = input("Enter Output Directory: ")
if len(output_dir) == 0:
    print("Actually Enter Enter Something")
    sys.exit()
rename(starting_dir, output_dir)
```

Comment: Has your code copy-pasted correctly? If so, one problem is that `return` should be at the same level of indentation as the rest of the `rename` function.

Comment: the **syntax** error is probably `fileiter = glob.iglob(os.path.join(dir1, r'*.mp4')` (missing a parens)

Comment: Semicolons aren't needed.  In Python, semicolons allow for multiple statements on the same line.

Comment: Please post the error message you are getting... Most likely, if you read it carefuly you'll find the exact place (and maybe the reason) of the problem

Comment: Asking how to fix a syntax error without showing the actual error message...

Answer (score 2):

In python, if you don't specify a return it automatically returns `None`. In your code, the indentation of your return statement is off. It is enough to just remove it. Here is the correct code:

```
import glob, os, datetime, sys, time, shutil


def rename(dir1, dir2):
    filenum = 1
    date = time.strftime("%d%m%Y")
    fileiter = glob.iglob(os.path.join(dir1, r'*.mp4'))
    for filen in fileiter:
        print(filen);
        filename = dir2 + filen + date + filenum + r'.mp4'
        filedir1 = dir1 + filen
        shutil.copy2(filedir1, dir2);
        filedir2 = dir2 + filen
        os.rename(filedir2, filename);
    print("Copying Done!");

starting_dir = input("Enter Input Directory: ")
if len(starting_dir) == 0:
    print("Actually Enter Enter Something")
    sys.exit()
output_dir = input("Enter Output Directory: ")
if len(output_dir) == 0:
    print("Actually Enter Enter Something")
    sys.exit()
rename(starting_dir, output_dir)
```